# Sync two computers and also use git

Tags: git, synchronization, bitbucket, unison

Here is my situation:

I have two machines- A desktop and a laptop the home folders of which I keep in sync using unison. This setup works fine as I can carry my work around and have everything readily aviable. Now I want to throw git into this mix.

I have a remote repo set up in bitbucket.org. What I want to be able to do is periodically commit code from any of the machines ( as both are in sync ). However I am wondering if I set up the same git in both the machines will that create a conflict. Also the files are synced using unison...how will this affect git is another thing that worries me.

Any pointers as to how I might achieve this will be most helpful.

Thank you all and regards,

Sameer

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t synchronize the Git directories via unison.  I keep all my source repositories in a `src` subdirectory of my personal files directory, and have it ignored in unison.

From my unison configuration:

```
root = /home/igor/
root = ssh://example.com/

path = files

ignore = Path files/src/*
```

Comment: I thought of that. But the thing is I commit only once in a while ( say when a feature I intend to add is complete ). However as I move around I'd like "src" at work to be in sync with the "src" in the laptop as when I reach home I can continue to work in my laptop

Comment: You could create kind of like a `sources.list` file in the `src` directory which lists the repositories you want to have checked out, and keep this file synced via unison (you could use the `ignorenot = Path files/src/sources.list` directive in your unison config).  Then, you’d need a build script that checks out all the repos listed in `sources.list` that aren’t there yet.  Still, you would have to push all commits in your repositories to a remote server to have them available at the other machine(s), but there is no alternative if you don’t want to sync the entire repos with unison.

Comment: I dont mind syncing my repo dirs with unison. But will doing that create conflicts? I would like to be able to commit from either the laptop or the desktop. the transition from one to the other should be seamless

Comment: It could potentially create conflicts if you first do something in one machine’s repo, and later in the same repo on the other machine without having synced them inbetween—i.e., you absolutely have to make sure to not forget syncing every time you switch machines.  Using plain Git to keep the repos in sync would be more forgiving, as you can always go the fetch-and-merge route.

Comment: I get the having to sync everytime I switch machines and frankly its a pain. But even using plain git...dont I have to push and pull each time i make the switch?

Comment: You can push/pull at any time.  Just think of it as two different developers working together on the same project.  This is what Git is all about, actually.

Answer (score 0):

I sync my computers using Dropbox, and I have a few git directories there. So basically my git files are sync'd too, and I've never had problems with this.

Comment: Apparently syncing git files is not a very good idea coz they tend to grow pretty fast and would eat into my dropbox space.